# Is there a way to get more volume levels on Android TV?

Tags: audio, android-tv, volume

I have an Android TV box, but the issue is that the volume level ranges from 0 to 10 at maximum, which is not precise at all.
For example, when I'm at 1, the sound is loud, so I want to lower it, but I can't because the level below is 0, and the sound cuts off. Therefore, I'm forced to lower the TV volume.

What I would like to know is if there is an application or a modification possibility with ADB or other means that would allow me to have more volume levels (for example: from 0 to 50 or from 0 to 100).

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others searching for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Comment: Is there a problem in using the TV remote to adjust the volume on the TV?